# How to cancel console closing after clicking Close button

Tags: c#, .net, console, event-handling

I have already tried all ways SO similar answers have showed me. None works.

So I need to capture the close button click event on my console application to ask the user if he/she really wants to close it. And I got it working, yes. The problem is that the console is closing anyway since I can't tell it not to do it.

I have tried the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new System.EventHandler(CurrentDomain_ProcessExit);` way but it never gets fired unless I explicitly call the function (with empty parameters, so still useless).

How can I cancel the close event in my .NET application?

Any help will be welcome!

My code right now:

```cs
enum CtrlType
{
    CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
    CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
    CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
    CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
    CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
}

private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);

[DllImport("Kernel32")]
private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);

private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Seguro que quieres cerrar la aplicación?", "Confirmación de cierre", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    switch (dr)
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(new object(), new CancelEventArgs());
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            return false;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
#endregion

#region Methods
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new EventHandler(Handler), true);
    Console.Title = GlobalConfig.Title;
    Console.Clear();
    init();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever found a way to do it?

Comment: @MeTitus I seem to remember I did not, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think that **returning true** on clicking **No/Cancel** should stop raising the default handler that is closing your application.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler
>   When a console process receives any of the control signals, its
>   handler functions are called on a last-registered, first-called basis
>   until one of the handlers returns TRUE. **If none of the handlers
>   returns TRUE, the default handler is called**.

Comment: It works for Ctrl+C case, but not when I close it via the X (close) button.